# Add dynamic property to content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

It may seem a very simple question. Suppose I want to check dynamically condition in order to add some property to some tag in some `Helper Module`:

```
def add_tag(hash)
    content_tag(:div, class: "some_class", rows: "#{check_rows(hash)}")
end

def check_rows(hash)
    hash[:rows].nil? ? "" : hash[:rows]
end
```

this works fine, but I don't want to make `rows` appear inside generated tags if `hash[:rows].nil?`. So I tried this

```
content_tag(:div, class: "some_class", "#{check_rows(hash)}")
```

and

```
   def check_rows(hash)
    hash[:rows].nil? ? "" : ":rows =>  hash[:rows]"
   end
```

but `"#{check_rows(hash)}"` is not recognized. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean with '"#{check_rows(hash)}" is not recognized'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the arguments for the content_tag method the wrong way round. Try this:

```
def add_tag(hash)
    content_tag(:div, check_rows(hash), class: "some_class")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
def add_tag(hash)
    content_tag(:div, class: "some_class", rows: "#{check_rows(hash)}")
end

def check_rows(hash)
    hash[:rows].nil? ? "" : hash[:rows]
end
```

with

```
def add_tag(hash)
   content_tag(:div, "#{check_rows(hash)}", class: "some_class")
end

def check_rows(hash)
   hash[:rows].nil? ? "" : {"rows" =>  hash[:rows]}
end
```

The reason it was not recognized was because you were passing `:rows =>  hash[:rows]` as a string whereas content_tag expected a hash.

Comment: Also do you want to display html content raw?